# Check if worksheet in workbook has specific name, and change it if it does

Tags: vba

I am currently writing a macro that is supposed to take the contents of a specific excel workbook and worksheet and copy them into another worksheet in a different workbook.

Not too difficult, but the problem that I am running into is that the worksheets that I am trying to pull info from have one of two names.  They are either `Sheet1` or `T Points to Measure`.

The current fix that I attempting to use (may not be the best) is to check if the worksheet has the name `T Points to Measure`.  If it does then I want to change it to `Sheet1` so all worksheets should have the same name.

My current code that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
Let Copyrange = "T - ATKB000" & serialno & " Ply Count Request"
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Copyrange)
wb2.Activate
If wb2.Worksheet.Name = "T Points to Measure" Then
    wb2.Worksheet.Name = "Sheet1"
End If
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is happening on this line of code:

```
If wb2.Worksheet.Name = "T Points to Measure" Then
```

specifically at `wb2.Worksheet`.  That is not valid vba syntax as there is no `Worksheet` method or property on the `Workbook` object.

There is a `Worksheets` property, which is what you need.  In order to access an individual worksheet, you need to use the `Worksheets` syntax with an index or loop through each worksheet in the workbook and check the names individually.  The if statement below will run without error, but it's kind of redundant.

```
If wb2.Worksheets("T Points to Measure").Name = "T Points to Measure" Then
```

Comment: If what if the worksheet really has the name `Sheet1'?  Won't that bring an error?

Comment: Yes, you'll get an error there too, but your '438' error comes from the improper syntax described above.

Comment: VBA has the old `OnError - Resume` syntax.  That might be what you're looking for.  You can do some reading up on that.